# flutter no longer works with Sonoma

Tags: flutter, dart

I upgraded to Sonoma and then also to flutter.
The Installation was successful, but at startup

```
Flutter doctor
```

I don't get any messages and it freezes, pressing Ctrl +c I see this message

> ^C[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.6, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64, locale it-IT)
> • Flutter version 3.13.6 on channel stable at /Users/mauriziomancini/FlutterDev/flutter
> • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
> • Framework revision ead455963c (31 ore fa), 2023-09-26 18:28:17 -0700
> • Engine revision a794cf2681
> • Dart version 3.1.3
> • DevTools version 2.25.0